# PHP MySQL Get Connection From Require() File

Tags: php, mysql

I usually am immersed in the Microsoft Stack but dabble in PHP from time to time. A long standing question I've had with PHP that I've never seem to be able to find the answer to is how do you apply your already declared `require("dbConnect.php")` database connection to your mysql_query()? For clarification please see my code example below:

```
        require("dbConnect.php"); 

        $db_host = 'localhost';
        $db_user = 'UserName';
        $db_pwd = 'Password';

        $database = 'DbName';
        $table = 'tblQuote';

        if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
            die("Can't connect to database");

        if (!mysql_select_db($database))
            die("Can't select database");

        // sending query
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT QuoteID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, Email, QuoteDate FROM tblQuote ORDER BY QuoteDate DESC");
        if (!$result) {
            die("Query to show fields from table failed");
        }

        $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
```

So in looking at this you can see the standard require() declaration at the top... which already holds my connection info. But every single MySQL Query example I've ever found always creates it's own connection... which I get for demonstration purposes... but I've never been able to figure out how I can use my already existing connection thereby bypassing rewriting the exact same connection info over and over again when it comes to writing queries. I know for you PHP developers this question is like 101 but I've not been able to find an answer to this seemingly basic question... admittedly I may be asking the question wrong so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: first the examples you have seen are wrong ones. your connection details should be in a separate file ( dbConnect.php in your example) and the file which in including the file should not have the connection details (this is the standard practice). Also note `mysql_` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed in PHP 7.x. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: @bansi Right... that's what I've imagined... but I've never seen a mysql_query() example that actually used the Require() connection as all examples I've seen create their own connections on the spot.

Comment: Please do not use the `mysql_*` functions, they are now depreciated. Use the `mysqli_*` functions please :)

Comment: Quick search in google [Creating Your First PHP Application](http://buildinternet.com/2009/12/creating-your-first-php-application-part-1/) Watch out for the formatting errors in theit code like `>` is shown as `&gt;`

Comment: @Matt ... yes thanks for that. This example I posted is actually an old one I've held on to for years... but it's been a while since I've delved into PHP so thanks for that reminder as I had almost forgotten.

Comment: some more links https://gist.github.com/jonashansen229/4534794  
[Using PHP with MySQL - the right way](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/using-php-with-mysql-the-right-way/17) 
[A Simple PHP Class For Prepared Statements in MySQLi](http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/simple-php-class-prepared-statements-mysqli/)

Comment: @bansi So... I should not use the require() connection and instead use a connection class like demonstrated in the post? Is that standard, or just a demonstrated alternative?

Comment: A connection class will save you a lot of trouble later. And it will be easier to code the other part of the application and easier to maintain.

Comment: @bansi Thank you... I think I will go that route after all. I could not award you the answer as you did not post it below so I'm only able to up-vote your comments... but thanks for your time and experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP documentation:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

```
mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

> link_identifier
>   The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments.

So since you've already created one in your dbConnect.php, the one you just made will be used (It won't create a new one for every query). To pass it explicitly into your `mysql_query` function call, you can return the MySQL resource that was returned from your mysql_connect call like so:

dbConnect.php

```
return mysql_connect(....);
```

Then in the code you pasted above:

```
$mysql_conn = require('dbConnect.php');
...
$result = mysql_query('...', $mysql_conn);
```

Then you will explicitly have the connection and pass it to your query - there will be no mistaking it, regardless of how large your codebase becomes. When you require the file, you'll have access to the connection variable, but in the above example, how you get the connection is more semantically clear.

---

***Also, notice that this function has been deprecated in PHP>=5.5, so you'll want to use PDOs or MySQLi which have future support.***

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sweet! Bansi in the comments to my question gave a few links to posts that showed a connection class that you can instantiate when needed. Is either method "Best Practice" i.e. mysqli() connections with a class or as you demonstrated above?

Comment: PDOs are going to give you the best functionality but that comes at a cost: they're tricky and sometimes awkward to use for simple tasks - their learning curve is higher. You can get the same functionality out of MySQLi, however you'll want to write a connection class like @bansi provided. "Using PHP with MySQL" looks like the best, most detailed example for you. Overall, I'd say give both PDOs and MySQLi a try. Write some proofs-of-concept and see which one you like better.